# makefile(36) : fatal error U1000: syntax error : ')' missing in macro invocation

Tags: makefile

Good evening.
I'm trying to compile a game server for an old game that I play, because I would like to host it for me and some friends. But even after a lot of tries I could not make it work, beccause I'm getting errors every time I try to compile it with nmake.
The error seems to be a ")" missing in line 36, altough I don't understand why. 
But if I put a ")" after "wildcard", I get the same error for line 37; if I add another ")" there after "patsubst", it tells me that a separator is missing in line 40.

```
    include ../makefile.inc

# LANG
# LC_KOR 0
# LC_TWN 1
# LC_CHN 3
# LC_TLD 4
# LC_JPN 6
# LC_JPNEP 6
# LC_MAL 7
# LC_USA 9
# LC_BRZ 10
# LC_HBK 11
# LC_GER 13
# LC_SPN 14
# LC_FRC 15
# LC_PLD 16
# LC_RUS 17
# LC_TUR 18
# LC_ITA 19
# LC_MEX 20
# LC_ESP_USA 21
# LC_FRA_USA 22
# LC_NLD 23
# LC_UK 24

TARGET=GameServer

TARGET_DEBUG=$(TARGET)_d
TARGET_TEST=$(TARGET)_t
TARGET_TESTDEBUG=$(TARGET)_td
TARGET_QA=$(TARGET)_q
TARGET_QADEBUG=$(TARGET)_qd
TARGET_NOXTRAP=$(TARGET)_noxtrap

LC_SRCS=$(wildcard *.cpp)
LC_OBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(LC_SRCS))

ifeq ($(LOCAL_PUB), gamigo)
OPT_LDOBJ += -ldl
endif

ifeq ($(LOCAL_PUB), rus)
OPT_LDOBJ += -ldl
endif

ifeq ($(LOCAL_PUB), usa)
OPT_LDOBJ += -ldl
endif

ifeq ($(LOCAL_PUB), bila)
OPT_LDOBJ += -ldl
endif

CXXFLAGS += -D__GAME_SERVER__

all: kor


kor:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_KOR=0 OPT_TEST=-DELENOATEST $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

kordebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_KOR=0 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

kortest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_KOR=0 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

korqa:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_KOR=0 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QA)

kortestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_KOR=0 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

korqadebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_KOR=0 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QADEBUG)

kordep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_KOR=0 $(MAKE) lcdep



twn:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TWN=1 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

twndebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TWN=1 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

twntest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TWN=1 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

twntestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TWN=1 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

twndep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TWN=1 $(MAKE) lcdep



jpn:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN=6 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

jpndebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN=6 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

jpntest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN=6 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

jpntestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN=6 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

jpndep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN=6 $(MAKE) lcdep



jpnep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN_EP=6 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

jpnepdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN_EP=6 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

jpneptest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN_EP=6 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

jpneptestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN_EP=6 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

jpnepdep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_JPN_EP=6 $(MAKE) lcdep



tld:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TLD=4 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

tlddebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TLD=4 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

tldtest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TLD=4 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

tldqa:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TLD=4 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QA)

tldtestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TLD=4 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

tldqadebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TLD=4 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QADEBUG)

tlddep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_TLD=4 $(MAKE) lcdep



mal:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MAL=7 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

maldebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MAL=7 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

maltest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MAL=7 OPT_TEST=-DMAL_TEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

maltestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MAL=7 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DMAL_TEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

maldep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MAL=7 $(MAKE) lcdep



usa:
    LOCAL_PUB=usa OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

usadebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=usa OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

usatest:
    LOCAL_PUB=usa OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

usaqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=usa OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QA)

usatestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=usa OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

usaqadebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=usa OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QADEBUG)

usadep:
    LOCAL_PUB=usa OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 $(MAKE) lcdep



brz:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ=10 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

brzdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ=10 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

brztest:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ=10 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

brztestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ=10 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

brzdep:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ=10 $(MAKE) lcdep



brzep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ_EP=10 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

brzepdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ_EP=10 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

brzeptest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ_EP=10 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

brzeptestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ_EP=10 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

brzepdep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_BRZ_EP=10 $(MAKE) lcdep



hbk:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_HBK=11 $(MAKE) $(TARGET) 

hbkdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_HBK=11 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG) 

hbktest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_HBK=11 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST) 

hbkqa:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_HBK=11 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QA) 

hbktestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_HBK=11 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG) 

hbkqadebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_HBK=11 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QADEBUG) 

hbkdep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_HBK=11 $(MAKE) lcdep 




ger:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

gerdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

gertest:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

gertestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

gerdep:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 $(MAKE) lcdep

gernoxtrap:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)



gerqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

gerdebugqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

gerdepqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) lcdep

gernoxtrapqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_GER=13 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)



spn:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

spndebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

spntest:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

spntestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

spndep:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 $(MAKE) lcdep

spnnoxtrap:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)



spnqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

spndebugqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

spndepqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) lcdep

spnnoxtrapqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_SPN=14 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)




frc:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

frcdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

frctest:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

frctestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

frcdep:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 $(MAKE) lcdep

frcnoxtrap:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)




frcqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

frcdebugqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

frcdepqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) lcdep

frcnoxtrapqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRC=15 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)



pld:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

plddebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

pldtest:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

pldtestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

plddep:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 $(MAKE) lcdep

pldnoxtrap:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)



pldqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

plddebugqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

plddepqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) lcdep

pldnoxtrapqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_PLD=16 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)



rus:
    LOCAL_PUB=rus OPT_LANG=-DLC_RUS=17 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

rusdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=rus OPT_LANG=-DLC_RUS=17 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

rustest:
    LOCAL_PUB=rus OPT_LANG=-DLC_RUS=17 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

rusqa:
    LOCAL_PUB=rus OPT_LANG=-DLC_RUS=17 OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QA)

rustestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=rus OPT_LANG=-DLC_RUS=17 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

rusqadebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=rus OPT_LANG=-DLC_RUS=17 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DQA_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_QADEBUG)

rusdep:
    LOCAL_PUB=rus OPT_LANG=-DLC_RUS=17 $(MAKE) lcdep



tur:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_TUR=18 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

turdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_TUR=18 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

turtest:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_TUR=18 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

turtestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_TUR=18 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

turdep:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_TUR=18 $(MAKE) lcdep
turnoxtrap:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_TUR=18 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)


ita:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_ITA=19 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

itadebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_ITA=19 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

itatest:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_ITA=19 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

itatestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_ITA=19 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

itadep:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_ITA=19 $(MAKE) lcdep

itanoxtrap:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_ITA=19 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_NOXTRAP)


mex:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX=20 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

mexdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX=20 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

mextest:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX=20 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

mextestdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX=20 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

mexdep:
    LOCAL_PUB=bila OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX=20 $(MAKE) lcdep




mexep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX_EP=20 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

mexepdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX_EP=20 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

mexeptest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX_EP=20 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

mexeptestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX_EP=20 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

mexepdep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_MEX_EP=20 $(MAKE) lcdep



espusa:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_ESP_USA=21 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

espusadebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_ESP_USA=21 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

espusatest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_ESP_USA=21 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

espusatestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_ESP_USA=21 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

espusadep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_ESP_USA=21 $(MAKE) lcdep




frausa:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRA_USA=22 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

frausadebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRA_USA=22 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

frausatest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRA_USA=22 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

frausatestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRA_USA=22 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

frausadep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_FRA_USA=22 $(MAKE) lcdep



nld:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_NLD=23 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

nlddebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_NLD=23 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

nldtest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_NLD=23 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

nldtestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_NLD=23 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

nlddep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_NLD=23 $(MAKE) lcdep



world:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_DEF=-DWORLD_TOURNAMENT=100 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

worlddebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_DEF=-DWORLD_TOURNAMENT=100 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)

worldtest:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_DEF=-DWORLD_TOURNAMENT=100 OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TEST)

worldtestdebug:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_DEF=-DWORLD_TOURNAMENT=100 OPT_DEBUG=-g OPT_TEST=-DTEST_SERVER $(MAKE) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG)

worlddep:
    OPT_LANG=-DLC_USA=9 OPT_DEF=-DWORLD_TOURNAMENT=100 $(MAKE) lcdep

uk:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_UK=24 $(MAKE) $(TARGET)

ukdebug:
    LOCAL_PUB=gamigo OPT_LANG=-DLC_UK=24 OPT_DEBUG=-g $(MAKE) $(TARGET_DEBUG)


$(TARGET): $(LC_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OPT_LINK) $(LC_OBJS) $(OPT_LDOBJ)

$(TARGET_DEBUG): $(LC_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OPT_LINK) $(LC_OBJS) $(OPT_LDOBJ)

$(TARGET_TEST): $(LC_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OPT_LINK) $(LC_OBJS) $(OPT_LDOBJ)

$(TARGET_TESTDEBUG): $(LC_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OPT_LINK) $(LC_OBJS) $(OPT_LDOBJ)

$(TARGET_QA):$(LC_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(LC_OBJS) $(OPT_LDOBJ)

$(TARGET_QADEBUG): $(LC_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(LC_OBJS) $(OPT_LDOBJ)

$(TARGET_NOXTRAP): $(LC_OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OPT_LINK) $(LC_OBJS) $(OPT_LDOBJ)

.cpp .o:
    $(CXX) -D__GAME_SERVER__ -c $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(patsubst %.o,%.cpp,$@)

lcdep: $(LC_SRCS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OPT_LANG) -M $(LC_SRCS) > .depend

clean:
    rm -rf $(LC_OBJS)


cleanall:
    find . -name "*.o" -exec rm -rf {} \;
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(TARGET_DEBUG) $(TARGET_TEST) $(TARGET_TESTDEBUG) $(TARGET_QA) $(TARGET_QADEBUG)

ifeq (.depend,$(wildcard .depend))
include .depend
endif

    enter code here
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is not an `nmake` makefile.  It's a GNU make makefile.  You can't use it with nmake; you'll have to install GNU make to use it.

Comment: Also, this makefile is written for a POSIX system, such as GNU/Linux.  It uses many commands and compilation flags which aren't available on Windows.  To build it you'll likely have to install something like Cygwin or MinGW, to get these tools.  Or you could start a virtual machine running a version of GNU/Linux on your Windows system and compile and run this game there--of course that has its own set of complications.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Since I already have a CentOS 6.9 virtual machine I tried to compile it there using the make command, but that did not work out either. Here is a screenshot of the result: http://grabilla.com/08c13-a107d005-ba56-44f8-a995-1e9cad83741d.png
I am a total beginner in that stuff sadly, so I have no idea what I could have done wrong.. Never done this before

Comment: I don't think a long conversation in comments about the steps you'll need to take to get this package built is really appropriate for a SO question.  In any event, this error says that the program `ccache` is not installed on your system, so you should install it.  Use something like `sudo yum install ccache`.

Comment: Done that, still having problems but I will just try to find a tutorial again, you're right this it not the right place for those long conversations. Thanks for your help tho!

Comment: It's very likely you'll need to install other tools and libraries as well.  Good luck!